# System Clean Up

Tags: system-installation, filesystem

How to uninstall unused apps leaving the ones you actually need?  We install app and packs to test and we find is not we want and the system starts getting slow.

Comment: Consider asking about how to troubleshoot a slow system instead of assuming that unused applications are the best answer. Unused applications generally do not occupy CPU or RAM, so cannot slow your system....

Comment: ...unless, of course, your have installed *lots* of snaps. Those will consume RAM, but are also easy to spot and remove.

Answer (score 0):

to uninstall a application from ubuntu, you type in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt remove <application to remove>
sudo apt autoremove
```

If you have installed a lot of apps and no longer know what they were:
the `history | grep "apt"` command let's you search in history after the word "apt". (hopefully finding the apps you have installed by apt)

Another, very useful command would be apropos. Which can search names and descriptions of applications manuals.